# Transformations and source info for data ditionary

Tags: ssis, transaction

I am currently building our data dictionary for our data warehouse, but two things we would like to add is the source for the fields, and the transformations that were applied to them. Is there a way to get the info from our ssis server to be included in our dictionary.